# How to activate UINavigationController and switch between them

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I built my own `TabBarController` based on `UIViewController` and `UIButtons`.  I prepared my viewControllers with UINavigationController(s).

How can I activate these views, how can I switch between them and How can I keep myTabBarController on top?

Answer (score 0):

Your structure should be like this:

```
TabBarController
|
|
|____NavController1
|    |
|    |
|    |____RootVC1
|
|
|____NavController2
|    |
|    |
|    |____RootVC2
|
|
|____NavController3
|    |
|    |
|    |____RootVC3
|
```

In your app delegate, you set the root view controller as your tabBarController controller.

Then for each of your custom tab-switching buttons, you can tell your tabBarController to set the selected index based on what the button pressed is:

```
-(void)button1Pressed
{
    myTabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

    // you might want to set your button's enabled graphic and set other button to disable graphic
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I am not using TabBarController and I tries to build it myself. I transferred the NacControllers array as you described above and I wish to know how to use them. SubView, pushViewController or presentModalViewController did not work for me. What is the correct method to activate these NacControllers+RootVC's